# Recursion - How can print each digit separately, rather than the sum of the number

Tags: java, recursion

input:

```
123
```

output:

```
6 >>> (It is the sum of all digits)
```

I want the output will:

```
321
```

That means each digit separately

What is wrong in the code?

The code:

```
public class t4 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(ReverseNum(123));
}

public static int ReverseNum(int num) {
    int dig = 0;
    if (num == 0)
        return dig;

    dig = dig * 10 + num % 10;

    return ReverseNum(num / 10) + dig;

}
}
```

thank's

Comment: So all you want is just to print the digits in reverse ? Say if input is "123" and you want the output to be in reverse "321". Is it ?

Comment: Is there any specific requirement that you need to go for recursion ?

Comment: public static String ReverseNum(int num) {
  String dig = "";
  if (num == 0) return dig;
  dig = Integer.toString(num % 10);
  return dig + ReverseNum(num / 10);
}

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public static void reverseMethod(int number) {
    if (number < 10) {
        System.out.println(number);
        return;
    }
    else {
        System.out.print(number % 10);
        reverseMethod(number/10);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
public class t4 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(ReverseNum(123));
}

public static String ReverseNum(int num) {
    if (num == 0)
        return "";


   return "" +  num % 10 + ReverseNum(num / 10);

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the largest power of ten smaller than the number first and use it to for reversing the number. This allows you to "move the digits to the right places":

```
public static int findPow10(int num) {
    if (num < 10) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 10 * findPow10(num / 10);
    }
}

private static int reverseHelper(int num, int factor) {
    if (num == 0) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return factor * (num % 10) + reverseHelper(num / 10, factor / 10);
    }
}

public static int reverse(int num) {
    return reverseHelper(num, findPow10(num));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(reverse(123));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than printing the values, I'm trying to return the number. This is what I could come up with so far. I think someone else might be able to do a better job. It's not that elegant with the while loop inside.

```
public static int ReverseNum(int num) {
    if (num < 10){
        return num;
    }
    int val = 1; int n = num;
    while(n > 10){
        n = n/10;
        val = val * 10;
    }

    return (num % 10)*val + ReverseNum((num - num % 10)/10);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    class Solution
{
    //A method for reverse
   public static void reverseMethod(int number) 
   {
       if (number < 10)
       {
       System.out.println(number);
       }
       else {
           System.out.print(number % 10); // 123 % 10 = 3
           //Method is calling itself: recursion
           reverseMethod(number/10); //123/10 = 12 integer ignore decimal number
           }
   }
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
     reverseMethod(123);

   }
}
```